# I want a function which merge the sub array if a particular value is same

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting

I have the 2D array as following:

[ [ 'Procare Fitted Hospital Bed Bottom Sheet, Ivory',
'DT4098',
'Demo',
null,
12300,
2],
[ 'Essential Medical Supply Deluxe Complete Hospital Bed Set',
'ERT665',
'Demo',
null,
11790,
2],
[ 'Dr. Morepen St 04 Acoustic Stethoscope',
'DT4098',
'Demo',
null,
21237,
2],
[ 'CosmoCare KLife 5 Para Patient Monitor',
'YTT690',
'Demo',
null,
11000,
2],
[ 'CosmoCare KLife 5 Para Patient Monitor',
'YTT690',
'Demo',
null,
11000,
2],
[ 'CosmoCare KLife 5 Para Patient Monitor',
'YTT690',
'Demo',
null,
11000,
2],
[ 'CosmoCare KLife 5 Para Patient Monitor',
'YTT690',
'Demo',
null,
11000,
2],
[ 'Dr. Morepen St 04 Acoustic Stethoscope',
'DT4098',
'Demo',
null,
21237,
2],
[ 'Essential Medical Supply Deluxe Complete Hospital Bed Set',
'ERT665',
'Demo',
null,
11790,
2],
[ 'Essential Medical Supply Deluxe Complete Hospital Bed Set',
'ERT665',
'Demo',
null,
11790,
2] ];

and I just want to remove duplicate values from a multidimensional array on the basis of the 1st index of the subarray. If the 1st index value is the same then remove the duplicate sub-array.

[ [ 'Procare Fitted Hospital Bed Bottom Sheet, Ivory',
'DT4098',
'Demo',
null,
12300,
6],
[ 'Essential Medical Supply Deluxe Complete Hospital Bed Set',
'ERT665',
'Demo',
null,
11790,
6],
[ 'CosmoCare KLife 5 Para Patient Monitor',
'YTT690',
'Demo',
null,
11000,
4]];

Comment: Use a set... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: You did not very well explain what is happening in this merge, how values are affected (totalled?), ...etc. Also, you should provide your attempt, and where you are stuck and get different results. Now it just sounds like "give me the codes" and deserves a downvote for not showing any effort.

Comment: You can get better responses with your questions by not beginning with "I want x". In your case, just start with "function which..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this help you.

```js
var myArray = [ [ 'Procare Fitted Hospital Bed Bottom Sheet, Ivory',
    'DT4098',
    'Demo',
    null,
    12300,
    2],
  [ 'Essential Medical Supply Deluxe Complete Hospital Bed Set',
    'ERT665',
    'Demo',
    null,
    11790,
    2],
  [ 'Dr. Morepen St 04 Acoustic Stethoscope',
    'DT4098',
    'Demo',
    null,
    21237,
    2],
  [ 'CosmoCare KLife 5 Para Patient Monitor',
    'YTT690',
    'Demo',
    null,
    11000,
    2],
  [ 'CosmoCare KLife 5 Para Patient Monitor',
    'YTT690',
    'Demo',
    null,
    11000,
    2],
  [ 'CosmoCare KLife 5 Para Patient Monitor',
    'YTT690',
    'Demo',
    null,
    11000,
    2],
  [ 'CosmoCare KLife 5 Para Patient Monitor',
    'YTT690',
    'Demo',
    null,
    11000,
    2],
  [ 'Dr. Morepen St 04 Acoustic Stethoscope',
    'DT4098',
    'Demo',
    null,
    21237,
    2],
  [ 'Essential Medical Supply Deluxe Complete Hospital Bed Set',
    'ERT665',
    'Demo',
    null,
    11790,
    2],
  [ 'Essential Medical Supply Deluxe Complete Hospital Bed Set',
    'ERT665',
    'Demo',
    null,
    11790,
    2] ];
   let duplicates = [];
    let output = myArray.reduce((t, i) => {
      if(duplicates.includes(i[1])) {
        let myArray = t.filter((item) => item[1] == i[1])[0];
        myArray[5] += i[5];
        t = t.filter((item) => item[1] != i[1]);
        i = myArray;
      } else {
        duplicates.push(i[1]);
      }
      t.push(i);      
      return t;
    }, []);
    
    console.log(output);
```